# Каким образом перемещать FramelessWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt5, framelesswindowhint, mousemoveevent, mousepressevent

Столкнулся с проблемой: при перемещении окна через `mousePressEvent` и `mouseMoveEvent` возникает вот такая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на виджет (в данном случае кнопка) и ведении мышки в сторону при попадании на "тело" окна окно дёргается.

Подскажите как еще можно реализовать перемещении `FramelessWindow` окна? 
Или же как можно устранить данную проблему?

**example.py**

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import *  



class Widget_settings(QWidget):
    """Doc."""

def __init__(self, parent=QMainWindow):
    """Doc."""
    super().__init__()

    self.initSubWindow()

def paintEvent(self, event):
    """PAINT EVENT."""
    QWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
    url = "https://6kcmxu3d7l.a.trbcdn.net/upload/files-new/f5/1c/3d/562610_1000x1000.jpg"
    pix = QPixmap()
    pix.loadFromData(requests.get(url).content)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
    painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pix)


def initSubWindow(self):
    """Doc."""
    self.setMinimumSize(700, 500)
    self.setMaximumSize(1100, 800)
    self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    settings_layout = QGridLayout()
    settings_layout.setContentsMargins(90, 50, 50, 50)
    self.setLayout(settings_layout)

    header_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    header_hbox.setContentsMargins(50, 0, 0, 0)
    settings_layout.addLayout(header_hbox, 1, 1, Qt.AlignHCenter, Qt.AlignTop)

    settings_label = QLabel("Settings")
    settings_label.setFont(QFont("Heuristica", 12))
    settings_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    header_hbox.addWidget(settings_label, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

    hide_btn = QPushButton("Hide")
    hide_btn.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
    hide_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)
    close_btn = QPushButton("Exit")
    close_btn.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
    close_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)

    close_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)
    header_hbox.addWidget(hide_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    header_hbox.addWidget(close_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

    mainBtn_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    mainBtn_vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
    settings_layout.addLayout(mainBtn_vbox, 2, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

    settings1 = QPushButton("Settings_1")
    settings1.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
    settings1.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
    settings2 = QPushButton("Settings_2")
    settings2.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
    settings2.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
    settings3 = QPushButton("Settings_3")
    settings3.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
    settings3.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
    quit_btn = QPushButton("Exit")
    quit_btn.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
    quit_btn.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
    quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

    mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings2, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings3, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
    mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(quit_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.oldPosition = event.globalPos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPosition)
    self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
    self.oldPosition = event.globalPos()

def closeEvent(self, event):
    event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget_settings()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не думаю, что вы собираетесь перетаскивать окно при нажатии на кнопку.

Как вариант, попробуйте. Обратите внимание на объект `self.pressing`.

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget_settings(QWidget):
# ------------------> ^^^^^^^  vvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------  # ???
#    def __init__(self, parent=QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                  # +++
        super().__init__()
        self.initSubWindow()

        self.pressing = False                                         # +++

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        QWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
        
        '''
        url = "https://6kcmxu3d7l.a.trbcdn.net/upload/files-new/f5/1c/3d/562610_1000x1000.jpg"
        pix = QPixmap()
        pix.loadFromData(requests.get(url).content)
        '''
        pix = QPixmap('im.png')      # !!! установите свое, то что выше закомментировано
        
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pix)


    def initSubWindow(self):
        """Doc."""
        self.setMinimumSize(700, 500)
        self.setMaximumSize(1100, 800)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        settings_layout = QGridLayout()
        settings_layout.setContentsMargins(90, 50, 50, 50)
        self.setLayout(settings_layout)

        header_hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        header_hbox.setContentsMargins(50, 0, 0, 0)
        settings_layout.addLayout(header_hbox, 1, 1, Qt.AlignHCenter, Qt.AlignTop)

        settings_label = QLabel("Settings")
        settings_label.setFont(QFont("Heuristica", 12))
        settings_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        header_hbox.addWidget(settings_label, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

        hide_btn = QPushButton("Hide")
        hide_btn.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
        hide_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)
        close_btn = QPushButton("Exit")
        close_btn.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
        close_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)

        close_btn.setMaximumSize(30, 30)
        header_hbox.addWidget(hide_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        header_hbox.addWidget(close_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

        mainBtn_vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        mainBtn_vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        settings_layout.addLayout(mainBtn_vbox, 2, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

        settings1 = QPushButton("Settings_1")
        settings1.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
        settings1.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
        settings2 = QPushButton("Settings_2")
        settings2.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
        settings2.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
        settings3 = QPushButton("Settings_3")
        settings3.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
        settings3.setMaximumSize(135, 55)
        quit_btn = QPushButton("Exit")
        quit_btn.setMinimumSize(100, 35)
        quit_btn.setMaximumSize(135, 55)

# ------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvcccc <------------------------  # ???
#        quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)
        quit_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)                                 # +++

        mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings2, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(settings3, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        mainBtn_vbox.addWidget(quit_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPosition = event.globalPos()
        self.pressing = True                                          # +++

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:                                             # +++
            delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPosition)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPosition = event.globalPos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):                               # +++
        self.pressing = False                                         # +++

    def closeEvent(self, event):                           
        event.accept()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget_settings()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это решило мою проблему. Благодарю!